# PHP - json_encode(string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) not escaping czech chars

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, json

I'm selecting some data from database and encoding them as json, but I've got a problem with czech signs like

> á,í,ř,č,ž...

My file is in utf-8 encoding, my database is also in utf-8 encoding, I've set header to utf-8 encoding as well. What else should I do please?

My code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
while($tmprow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row['user'] = mb_convert_encoding($tmprow['user'], "UTF-8", "auto");
        $row['package'] = mb_convert_encoding($tmprow['package'], "UTF-8", "auto");
        $row['url'] = mb_convert_encoding($tmprow['url'], "UTF-8", "auto");
        $row['rating'] = mb_convert_encoding($tmprow['rating'], "UTF-8", "auto");

        array_push($response, $row);
    }

    $json = json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    if(!$json) {
        echo "error";
    }
```

and part of the printed json: `"package":"zv???tkanalouce"`

**EDIT:** Without mb_convert_encoding() function the printed string is empty and "error" is printed.

Comment: If you want to output JSON, do not set `Content-Type: text/html` in your header, use `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: Just tell your database driver with that connection you're expecting UTF-8 encoded string values, throw away the mb_convert_encoding  you've plugged in there (there is no "auto" with encoding, you either know what you do or you're shooting in your own feets, there is no computer who can take over that for you) and you should be fine.

Comment: What do you expect `mb_convert_encoding($tmprow['rating'], "UTF-8", "auto")` to do? Why is it necessary? What stands the `"auto"` encoding parameter for? Does it mean you don't know which encoding your strings have and in which you need them to be? Please share.

Comment: @Holt It looks nicer now, but those chars are still appearing like '?', but thanks

Comment: @hakre "auto" should stand for automatic detection of input encoding.

Comment: @2rec: Important info: There is no such thing of automatic encoding detection. It's always a guess, do not rely to it. Especially not in cases where you run into trouble. Then it's time to throw such things out and find out about the actual encodings and control those. Drop the detection. Do you know how to specify the encoding for the database connection?

Comment: @hakre If I remove mb_convert_encoding function, it's printing an empty string.

Comment: @2rec: `json_encode` does not always return a string. In case of an error, it returns boolean FALSE which when echo'ed is an empty string. You need to check the return value first and deal with the error case. That's required for stable code.

Comment: @hakre I don't know how to specify that, could you give me some function I could search for please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51529/discussion-between-2rec-and-hakre)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the code you've got in your example, the output is:

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
"package":"zv???tkanalouce"
```

You see the question marks in there because they have been introduced by `mb_convert_encoding`. This happens when you use encoding detection ("`auto`" as third parameter) and that encoding detection is not able to handle a character in the input, replacing it with a question mark. Exemplary line of code:

```
$row['url'] = mb_convert_encoding($tmprow['url'], "UTF-8", "auto");
```

This also means that the data coming out of your database is *not* UTF-8 encoded because `mb_convert_encoding($buffer, 'UTF-8', 'auto');` does not introduce question marks if `$buffer` is UTF-8 encoded.

Therefore you need to find out which charset is used in your database connection because the database driver will convert strings into the encoding of the connection.

Most easy is that you just tell per that database link that you're asking for UTF-8 strings and then just use them:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
```

The previous code example just shows how to set the default client character set to UTF-8 with mysqli. It has been [taken from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php), see as well the material we have on site about that, e.g. [utf 8 - PHP and MySQLi UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10331883/367456).

You can then greatly improve your code:

```
$response = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

if (FALSE === $json) {
    throw new LogicException(
        sprintf('Not json: %d - %s', json_last_error(), json_last_error_msg())
    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo $json;
```