# encoding to UTF8 for JSON result using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8, latin1

I have been trying to solve this for more than a week.

I have a **MySQL** database **utf8_general_ci**.

When I print the result in **JSON** formate using php, the characters are not **UTF8** encoded.

The values stored in the database are in arabic language

Here is the code I'm using

**db.php**

```
<?php

$DBhost = "xx.xx.xx.x";
$DBusername = "username";
$DBpassword = "password";
$db_name = "bdname";

$connect = mysql_connect("$DBhost", "$DBusername", "$DBpassword")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>
```

and code to print the results are

**Show.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$tbl_name = "table_name";

mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");

$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $r);
}

print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Example of the output:

**[{"id":"4","news_id":"1","caption":"\u00c3\u0083\u00c3\u008e\u00c3\u0088\u00c3\u0087\u00c3\u0091 \u00c3\u0087\u00c3\u00a1\u00c3\u0088\u00c3\u0098\u00c3\u00a6\u00c3\u00a1\u00c3\u0089 \u00c3\u0087\u00c3\u00a1\u00c3\u00a3\u00c3\u008f\u00c3\u0091\u00c3\u0093\u00c3\u00ad\u00c3\u0089 \u00c3\u0087\u00c3\u00a1\u00c3\u008e\u00c3\u0087\u00c3\u00a3\u00c3\u0093\u00c3\u0089 \u00c3\u00a1\u00c3\u009f\u00c3\u0091\u00c3\u0089 \u00c3\u0087\u00c3\u00a1\u00c3\u009e\u00c3\u008f\u00c3\u00a3"**

What I understood from my search that the **/u00** is a **latin1** and the **UTF8** should start with **/u0** not two 0.

Tried different methods for converting **latin1** to **UTF8** like **iconv** and **decode_json** , changing the **mysql_set_charset** to **latin1** and even removing it, added html header using **UTF8,latin1 and windows-1526** charset also the same results and sometime i get **null** result for the **caption** output.

I'm out of options here and really don't know what to do

any idea ?

Comment: have you tested the mbstring functions, http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php, or a good tutorial http://www.ar-php.org/faq-php-arabic.html

Comment: Do those escape sequences represent the *wrong* characters or do you just want to use different escape sequences to represent non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @Quentin i want the result to be in utf8

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire i'll give it a try now

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire what tutorial link is not working, and didn't understand what to do from the other link, can you please explain how to do the test ?

Comment: @aLFaRSi — It's currently in ASCII, which is a subset of UTF-8, so it is in UTF-8.

Comment: @Quentin then why i'm not seeing the characters in arabic language ? how can i fix this please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322312/php-json-encodestring-json-unescaped-unicode-not-escaping-czech-chars

Comment: @Prashant not working also

Answer (score 3):

Include the next header in your .php file

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
...
```

and add 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in your json_encode

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Be sure to remove the utf8_encode() unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` you get `utf-8` encoded data from MySQL databse. Don't use`array_map('utf8_encode', $r)` on this data - this is your mistake. Correct one is:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```