# php encode JSON from mysql db but it shows "???" data

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

API link :: http://www.nobannoo.com/AppLandingPage/text.php

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM tc_cerealname";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$userData = array();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $userData['All Cereal Name'][] = $row;  
}
echo json_encode($userData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Output :: 
    "id": "1",
    "cereal_name_en": "Paddy",
    "cereal_name_bn": "???"

Desired Output ::
    "cereal_name_bn": "ধান"

Comment: perhaps this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322312/php-json-encodestring-json-unescaped-unicode-not-escaping-czech-chars

Comment: doesn't help much

Comment: What exactly doesn't help? The answer there suggests two things that are relevant here: 1.) It suggests to send the output as JSON, by adding `header('content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');` (I just added a charset to be sure it's utf-8) 2.) It also suggests to make sure the database connection uses UTF-8 as well. It describes it for mysqli, but on php.net I found a comment which describes a possible solution for PDO: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#113498

Answer (score 0):

See 'question marks' in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored/38363567)

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

Do you have

```
$DBCon->set_charset('utf8');
```

(or utf8mb4).

But, I suspect the data was not properly stored.  See the notes in that link for doing `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...`.